# Sunspot - How to use a regex with sunspot SOLR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

I'm using Rails 3.1.10 with sunspot gem.
How can I use Regexp or equivalent in my SOLR query ?
For example, search term "Mart" will return : "Marti", "Martin, "Martin Luther", ...

Comment: You can't use RegEx in Solr queries, but you can use wildcards like `Mart*`.